# I can't get rsync --exclude-from to work with a file

Tags: rsync

Here's the command :

```
rsync -avAX --exclude-from=rsyncexclude.txt ./some_tests/ ./back_to_me/
```

Here's the contents of the exclude file :

```
/some_tests/musik/
/some_tests/notthis/
```

I've tried the command from the Arch page - can't get that to work with the {} exclude either.

Not sure what to do, I'm not getting error messages, the directories exist. The directories that I don't want to be copied (that are on the txt file) are being copied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root (`/`) of an absolute path in an rsync exclude file refers to the top level of the source directory.  So if `./some_tests/` has an *internal* hierarchy that includes another `some_tests` subdirectory, then what you have should work.  I.e., `./some_tests/some_tests/musik/` should be excluded.

However, if what you meant was `./some_tests/musik/`, then you should use:

```
/musik/
```

Not `/some_tests/musik/`.

Comment: hi @goldilocks, that still doesn't work for me. no errors, just doesn't work.

Comment: -> that's working now thanks very much. I still can't get it working in my (python) script, thats outside the scope of this though I think.